# Problems with {directionsService} API of Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to learn Google Maps API to get directions from Point-A to Point-B. When I simply try the sample code from the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial), my Javascript console takes me to some code section that I cannot understand and the debugger is stopped at a line that reads "See the Terms of Service for more information: http://www.google.com/help/terms_maps.html.". Following is my html code listing:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var directionsDisplay;
      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      var map;

      function initialize() {
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 10,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }

      function calcRoute() {
        initialize()
        var start = "Sydney, NSW";
        var end = "Chatswood, NSW";
        var request = {
            origin:start,
            destination:end,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          }
        });
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="calcRoute()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The map does get displayed in the browser, but the directions do not show up. Can anybody see the problem here? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is that your key? Try without the key when you load the API. Where are you running it from? localhost? Some domain server? Is the key authorized for the domain?

Comment: Yes, that "was" my key. I had it up there accidentally :-) I removed it now. I am running it on a localhost...just created an html file, copy pasted the code, made some edits and then tried to open the page on a browser. What should I do to try it without the key? Just remove the key like the following:
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=false">
    </script>

Comment: I tried without the key as follow, but I get the same result:
`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>`

Comment: Yes, that's how you remove the key. However, geocodezip has already spotted the problem. :-)

Comment: Beware that with v=3.exp you're loading the **experimental** version. (not recommended for production sites)

Comment: Thanks for your help with this as well @Marcelo. So for production site, should I just remove `v=3.exp`? like the following:
`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=false"></script>`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20888/discussion-between-srinath-and-marcelo)

Comment: Yeps! ;-) -- You're welcome and good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the order of these two lines:

```
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);
```

Reverse them and it should work, setting the map of the Directions Renderer to null (or undefined), removes the directions from the map. I changed them to (so the map is assigned to the global map variable):

```
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
```

[Working Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_directionsService.html)

**code snippet:**

```js
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}

function calcRoute() {
  initialize()
  var start = "Sydney, NSW";
  var end = "Chatswood, NSW";
  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
}
@media print {
  html,
  body {
    height: auto;
  }
  #map_canvas {
    height: 650px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<body onload="calcRoute()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @geocodezip!! That was indeed silly of me to have declared/initialized `map` after it was being used. I copied it from somewhere and just assumed that it would work